# How can you convert an escaped hexadecimal number in R to a hex number formatted for html

Tags: html, r, hex

For example:
R has an emoji escaped as "\U0001f923" and I want to pass it to an html file where its format becomes usable as the characters: & # x 1 f 9 2 3 ; ().

How can you convert an escaped hexadecimal number in R to a hex number formatted for html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine the functions `utf8ToInt` and `as.hexmode`, then just paste the escaping characters on:

```r
as.html <- function(x) paste0("&x", as.hexmode(utf8ToInt(x)), ";")
as.html("\U0001f923")
#> [1] "&x1f923;"
```

You can use this to replace multi-byte characters like so:

```r
replace_multibytes <- function(x)
{
  as.html <- function(x) paste0("&x", as.hexmode(utf8ToInt(x)), ";")
  char_list <- as.list(unlist(strsplit(x, "")))
  x <- sapply(char_list, function(y) if(length(charToRaw(y)) > 1) as.html(y) else y)
  paste0(x, collapse = "")
}
```

So now you can do

```r
replace_multibytes("The following need replaced: \U0001f923 \U0001f924")
#> [1] "The following need replaced: &x1f923; &x1f924;"
```

Comment: amazing, thanks! Now, I'm wondering if you had any advice with regards to applying this function to replace the hex numbers while iterating through a vector of strings that may or may not contain any hex numbers as part of the text. Essentially, do you know how one could easily detect a hex number in a string?

Comment: OK nevermind again, that proved useless. Any advice?